# Having trouble with checkmouse

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble figuring out how to undraw something when there is a mouse click within a particular object (rectangle). I want the code to work in the way that when I click in the rectangle it erases the text (because I have to draw something else).

My professor doesn't like us to be importing a bunch of different libraries etc., so a simple method is much preferred.
The graphics library that we use from Zelle can be found here:
http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py

Here is the code I have now.

```
#... is a game to celebrate the 150th anniversay of ...
#The aim of the game is for players to complete a maze , but only
#with the least number of moves possible, and crossing the least number of
#trip wires. BoilerMazer keeps track of the names, moves, and scores. Then
#will also display the top players and scores.

from graphics import *

#creating the game panel window
def panel():
    #grey window, with coordinates flipped, with banners etc
    win = GraphWin("Start Panel", 300,200)
    win.setCoords(0,0,300,200)
    win.setBackground("light grey")
    #drawing the BoilerMazer banner with text
    boilermazer = Rectangle(Point(0,200),Point(300,160))
    boilermazer.setFill("white")
    boilermazer.draw(win)
    #text inside
    banner1 = Text(Point(150,180),"BoilerMazer")
    banner1.setStyle("bold")
    banner1.setSize(20)
    banner1.draw(win)
    #initial game panel is going to have two buttons and a top scores object
    #top score "screen"
    toprec = Rectangle(Point(60,140),Point(240,50))
    toprec.setFill("white")
    toprec.draw(win)
    #text inside toprec
    topscores = Text(Point(150,130),"TOP SCORES")
    topscores.setSize(8)
    topscores.draw(win)
    border = Text(Point(150,120),"======")
    border.draw(win)
    bigmac = Text(Point(150,110),"Big Mac     21")
    bigmac.setSize(8)
    bigmac.draw(win)
    tt = Text(Point(150,90),"T.T     23")
    tt.setSize(8)
    tt.draw(win)
    cshell = Text(Point(150,75),"C-Shell     25")
    cshell.setSize(8)
    cshell.draw(win)
    macmac = Text(Point(150,55),"MacMac     27")
    macmac.setSize(8)
    macmac.draw(win)
    #new player button that will eventually be clicked
    new1 = Point(90,35)
    new2 = Point(210,0)
    newrec = Rectangle(new1,new2)
    newrec.setFill("chartreuse2")
    newrec.draw(win)
    #new player button text
    newplayer = Text(Point(150,18),"NEW PLAYER")
    newplayer.draw(win)
    #reset button
    resetrec = Rectangle(Point(240,35),Point(300,0))
    resetrec.setFill("red")
    resetrec.draw(win)
    #resettext
    reset = Text(Point(270,18),"RESET")
    reset.draw(win)
    #secondary panel window is the game panel after they click new player
    clicknew = win.checkMouse()




#defining the main function that will hold and call all other functions
def main():
    #calling the panel function that draws the window
    panel()


main()
```

Comment: What is `graphics`? I don't believe it's part of the standard library.

Comment: graphics is the graphics library from python it's from the zelle package graphics.py

Comment: Would you mind adding a URL pointing to the homepage of that library?

Comment: sure here is the library! http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py